# SSIS Package not loading data from Sharepoint to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have this issue where I am trying to load data from a Sharepoint library (filtered) to a SQL Server database.

When I preview the Data Flow step, I can see the data. But when I run the package, it's successful but the Data Flow pulls 0 rows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your connection manager uses a dynamic expression (connection string perhaps). It's a long shot but are you sure it's connecting to the correct server when you run the package ?

Comment: Yeps, pretty sure. Anyways, Thanks for the feedback, I got it to work already. I noticed that there were control flows prior before it hits the one that has the data flow in question. Thanks again.